# EL&U chat room appearing on wrong page of room search results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, chat-search

An EL&U chatroom created yesterday is showing up, not on the first or second page of recently created rooms, but on page 38. This is with the sort=created and nohide=true options.

[Link to page 38 of the room list](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=created&page=38&nohide=true&host=english.stackexchange.com)

[Link to the room in question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44390/room-for-med-and-tonepoet)

Answer (score 8):

Discussion rooms (those that are imported from comments) and pair-off rooms (created via "start a new room with this user") are always sorted after all the other rooms, regardless of the sort order. If they were sorted inline, the room list would be fairly unusable because the normal rooms (that most people care about) would simply be drowned out.